# What could you do with the "Daft Club" card on daftcard.com?

Tags: daft-punk

My release of Daft Punk’s album [*Discovery*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery_%28Daft_Punk_album%29) contains a card (in [ID-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7810#ID-1) format):

```
DAFT CLUB

51… … … …
MEMBER PERSONAL ACCESS CODE

EXPIRATION 12/…       www.daftcard.com
```

The domain *daftcard.com* seems to be grabbed by someone else now.

The linked Wikipedia article only says:

> Early versions of the album included a "Daft Club" membership card. The card included a code which granted access to an online music service, which featured tracks later released on the album of the same name [Daft Club] and Alive 1997.

**What exactly could you do with the card’s code on daftcard.com?**

Which tracks did it feature? For streaming and/or for download?
Anything else? Maybe background information? Or a community forum?

Comment: It was one of the first CD's to feature a free digital copy of the CD.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can see various incarnations of the site on archive.org, e.g one of the later captures: http://web.archive.org/web/20021201095533/www.daftclub.com/index.php

Clicking on the links there, the tracks available were:

```
 FACE TO FACE 
 face to fate mix by demon 6.41 MB 

 CRESCENDOLLS 
 laidback luke remix - 4.75 MB 

 HARDER,BETTER,FASTER,STRONGER 
 neptunes instrumental - 4.33 MB 

 HARDER,BETTER,FASTER,STRONGER 
 jess & crabbe remix - 4.83 MB 

 HARDER,BETTER,FASTER,STRONGER 
 accapella - 2.30 MB 

 HARDER,BETTER,FASTER,STRONGER 
 instrumental - 3.14 MB 

 DIGITAL LOVE 
 club edit (boris dlugosch) - 6.08 MB 

 AERODYNAMIC 
 slum village remix - 3.09 MB 

 DAFT LIVE 
 45 mn concert - 38.9 MB 

 PHOENIX 
 basement jaxx remix - 6.61 MB 

 AERODYNAMIC SPECIAL 
 one more time/aerodynamic- 5.07 MB 

 ONE MORE TIME 
 unplugged accapella - 2.87 MB 

 OUVERTURE 
 2.16 MB
```

It seems that most of these are also available on the Daft Club CD you mentioned.

Looking at other dates on archive.org (e.g. http://web.archive.org/web/20010428034106/http://www.daftcard.com/), it seems like there was initially some custom software available for PC, [which used Intertrust DRM](http://web.archive.org/web/20020804141558/http://www.daftcard.com/en/installationhelpindex_1.php). Later on it says "The tracks can be played on Mac's and PC's using any standard player", so it seems they gave up on the DRM.

Comment: Nice, thanks :) Interestingly, they [advised](http://web.archive.org/web/20010429020654/http://www.daftcard.com/en/machelp_1.php) Mac users, which couldn’t install the DRM software, to check file sharing sites: "For your information, we have been told that the new Daft Punk track "Ouverture" is already available as a MP3 file on many popular sharing file sites, such as Napster and Macster, accessible with a Mac."